# docker build is overwriting the defined CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to make a change in an existing docker-image as follows.

1. Create a Dockerfile with below content

   FROM /solr:8.9.0

   USER root

   RUN some-command

   USER solr
2. Build an image using the below command
   docker build -t /solr:8.9.0.2 .

The issue i am facing is that it is overwiting "CMD" under "ContainerConfig", below is the snippet. Note: i am checking this with the command "docker inspect"

```
    "ContainerConfig": {                      "ContainerConfig": {
      ….                                                   ….
      ….                                                   ….
        "Cmd": [                                        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",                                      "/bin/sh",
            "-c",                                           "-c",
            "#(nop) ",                                      "#(nop) ",
            "CMD [\"solr-foreground\"]"                     "USER solr"
                   ],                                                   ],
```

If i define CMD as below

CMD ["solr-foreground"]

Then instead of overwriting in the section "ContainerConfig", it is writing under a separate section of "Config": {
Also the output observed is as shown below

```
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "[\\\"solr-foreground\\\"]"
        ],
```

if i try to spin up a kubernetes images it goes into crashloop.

Comment: You have an empty RUN, and the image refer for both the FROM and `docker build` lines contains an invalid leading `/`. Also `ContainerConfig` can likely be ignored, it's the values in `Config` you should be looking at.

Comment: @BMitch my run command was not empty, i have edited the post to rectify the same.
Could you please take a look at it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue i am facing is that it is overwiting "CMD" under "ContainerConfig"

That is not an issue. This is just some internals showing the temporary image that was used to create the last layer. It's not used when the runtime starts the container. Instead you should be looking at the "Config" section.